# jQuery Mobile specify page animation from submit button

Tags: jquery-mobile

When creating a form in jQuery mobile, it seems like the default form functionality is to specify the page load animation from the `<form>` tag rather than the submit button. I am trying to build a form with two submit buttons that are each supposed to perform a different animation (it sounds weird, but it makes sense in the context of the app. but that's not the point of the question :) )

Is there a way that I can get around the default specification in the `<form>` tag and specify the animation in the `<input>` tag for each submit button instead? So here's what I'm going for:

```
//this is where I have to specify the animation now, but I only want one button
//to trigger a "pop" animation
<form action='blah.php' data-transition='pop'>
    //form elements and whatnot

    //I'd like this button to have one animation by specifying it here:
    <input type='submit' value='submit button 1' data-transition='slide'>

    //And this button to have a different animation by specifying it here:
    <input type='submit' value='submit button 2' data-transition='pop'>
```

Right now, the transitions specified in the `<input>` tags are ignored whether or not I specify a transition in the `<form>`

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: I could be wrong, but the action page, `blah.php` in this case, would need to somehow have the `data-rel="dialog"` attribute joined to the form submit. I believe (and again, I could be wrong) that the only way to get the effect you're going for hinders on the jQuery mobile UI to detect it as a dialog. If you have a jsfiddle demo or something I may be able to be more help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I can create a fiddle to demonstrate this. The transitions only work with same-domain links. I tried experimenting with the AJAX examples they offer, but it doesn't seem to return anything without POSTing to the page.

But I don't think the lack of `data-rel` is the problem. The "pop" animation works fine when I specify it in the `<form>` tag. My question is finding a way to specify the animation that I want from the `<input>` tag for the individual submit tags instead of the `<form>` so I can have a different animation depending on which button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be i would be wrong, I think Submit button do not support transitions, but anchor tag does.. Try this by using anchor tag...

For Example,

```
<form action="blah.php" method="get">
<a id="direct1" data-transition="slide">submit button 2</a>
<a id="direct2" data-transition="pop">submit button 2</a>
</form>
```

If this code does run then try add `data-ajax="false"` on anchors....

Answer (score -1):

Just put data transitions on the `<form>` tag.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" data-transition="slideup" data-direction="reverse">
...your content form here...
</form>
```

Works even if your POST management page sets a location header to another page.

Comment: But the point of the question was that I need each button to perform a different animation so I needed an alternative to specifying in the `<form>` tag